# Remap Enter in command history edit window only

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, command-history

I currently have `<Enter>` mapped to `:nohlsearch` in normal mode. This allows me to leave search highlighting on for all new searches, but easily turn it off when it (soon after usually) becomes a distraction.

This works great usually, the exception is when I'm using `q:` to edit the command history to produce a closely related ex command or whatever. The behavior of Enter in that context is to execute the command (or search in search history edit), but the normal-mode remapping overrides that. Consequently, I need to hit enter from insert mode to execute the command.

How can I map Enter to `:nohlsearch` in normal mode but retain the "execute" behavior of Enter in the command-history edit window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the following in my vimrc to force regular behavior of enter in certain situations:

```
augroup vimrc_CRfix
  au!

  " Quickfix, Location list, &c. remap <CR> to work as expected
  autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
  autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>

augroup END
```

I cannot remember why I’m using `nnoremap` and not `unmap <buffer>`; it’s possible the latter works.

Comment: Super-awesome, this works! :)

Comment: Since you are using a buffer local mapping (i.e. `<buffer>`) it takes precedence over the global `<cr>` mapping so you do not need to `unmap`. Another thought: `nnoremap <buffer> <expr> <cr> v:hlsearch ? ":nohlsearch\<cr>" : "\<cr>"` which will disable the search if the search is active & if there is no search give you the normal `<cr>` behavior. See `:h :map-local`, `:h :map-<expr>`, and `:h v:hlsearch` for more

Comment: @PeterRincker i think the second half could be an additional answer; mine is more general because of the way mapping i use for `<CR>`